# PyWinAuto : Automation stops when screen is not responding

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, pywinauto

So, I am trying to automate an application using PyWinAuto. The application that I am automating stops responding for a few seconds in between and continues without any problem. But as soon as the tool window becomes "Not responding" it stops executing the script.

I tried adding delay, but there are not fixed point in automation where it behaves like this, whenever it stops responding it continues after some time. What can I do to overcome this issue?

Another issue that I face is that I cannot do overnight automation as the automation stops as soon as the remote desktop is closed, which is unlike other automation tools that we use. It shows this error -

`RuntimeError: There is no active desktop required for moving mouse cursor!`

This ruins the entire reason for automating the task. Kindly give your valuable suggestion regarding this too.

Comment: There are few ways to wait until the UI is ready: [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html). Please call some wait first, then try to do mouse actions. Also it's important to know which backend you are using for `Application` object.

Comment: I did use wait operation, but its not sure as to when exactly it will occur. I am using 'uia' backend for application. Also the RDP execution guide didn't go as expected. It still stops the automation. I did see few methods over which it does not work. But I cannot proceed without using those methods. What is the use of "automation" if it cannot run in a minimized rdp or locked screen?

Comment: I'd suggest to wait only for CPU usage since it doesn't touch any window. Maybe it will help to overcome this fragile mode. Regarding RDP issues, there is also an option to use VNC server instead of RDP if your company policy allows it.